# Deploying minimal OS for running Powershell scheduled tasks?

Tags: docker, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2016, vmware-esx, windows-server-2019

I need your suggestion and guidance in deploying minimal Operating System to run multiple **Powershell** Scheduled tasks on my OnPremise Hypervisor VMware v6.7

Typically, I am installing these modules

```
Active Directory
VMware PowerCLI,
Microsoft 365 (Office 365) 
Azure reporting.
```

Which one should be better for my scenario above?

```
Docker
Windows Server Core
Windows Server Nano
```

Comment: Without any details on the tasks, this is pure guessing. The minimal setup for "most" business tasks is core, though.

Comment: @bjoster, the task is to synch and update AD attributes every 60 minutes, run some compliance report every 60 minutes, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy in On-Premises installation I'll recommend you a Server Core.
Nano is headless and is built with cloud in mind. You can always benefit from an Hypervisor Console access with a Core installation.

I don't really know what Docker deployment do you want to do, but unless you already have a Docker infraestructure in place, it seems like a waste of time and resources only for a traditional VM use case.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you